# How to manage service account token usage in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, amazon-iam, hashicorp-vault

When a ServiceAccount created in Kubernetes a secret will be created too. This secret contains ServiceAccountToken. This token can be used in CI pipelines, even in kubectl and any where else to access the cluster.
Assume a developer in company copy this token for himself (and no ones know that) and after he left the company he still have access to our Kubernetes cluster. I want to limit his access. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a service account to interact with a kubernetes cluster from outside the cluster using kubectl or CI/CD systems is not the best approach from security point of view. You should rather use a [authenticating proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authenticating-proxy) wherein generation and rotation of short lived JWT token is delegated to an external OpenId/oAuth complaint authorization system.

Service accounts should only be used from a pod running inside the cluster and you can limit the authorization of the service account by [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) Role and RoleBinding. Keep in mind that currently service account tokens are not rotated by kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

> Assume a developer in company copy this token for himself (and no ones know that) and after he left the company he still have access to our Kubernetes cluster. I want to limit his access. How can I do that?

Yes, this is a risk that you have to mitigate.

In Kubernetes, you can now use tokens that are only valid for a short time, e.g. an hour. If you can, use [Service Account from a projected volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection). See also [No more forever tokens](https://thenewstack.io/no-more-forever-tokens-changes-in-identity-management-for-kubernetes/). In fact, I think this is a better approach for most Service Account usage - from a security standpoint.

If you use a Kubernetes-native CI/CD Pipeline, e.g. by using [Tekton](https://tekton.dev/) you can deploy using these newer tokens that are rotated regularly.

If you deploy from outside the cluster, @Arghya Sadhu provided a good alternative, by using an authentication proxy.

### Using Kubernetes at a cloud provider?

If you use Kubernetes at a cloud provider and deploy from a CI/CD outside of the cluster, they usually have federated identity solutions, e.g. [AWS IAM roles for EKS service accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) or [Google Workload Identity for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/introducing-workload-identity-better-authentication-for-your-gke-applications)